# 09▀30≈ß#@÷g gets displayed when i had not passed this String

Tags: java, c, unicode, utf-8, java-native-interface

I am trying to pass a String to a native `c` function but the String gets printed as `09▀30≈ß#@÷g` for the String `Type a String :` . I don't know what the problem is .

This is the code that i have used to do this :

**JAVA CODE**

```
class Prompt {

private native String myGetLine( String prompt ); // native method that prints a prompt and reads a line 

public static void main( String args[] ) {
Prompt prompt = new Prompt();
String input = prompt.myGetLine( "Type a String : ");
System.out.println("User Typed : " + input);
}

static {
 System.loadLibrary("StringPassing"); // StringPassing.dll
 }
}
```

**C CODE**

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "D:\UnderTest\JNI\StringPassing\Debug\Prompt.h"

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_Prompt_myGetLine(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jstring str) {
char buf[128];
const jbyte *str_JVM;
str_JVM = (*env) -> GetStringUTFChars( env , str , NULL);
if( str_JVM == NULL ) return NULL;
printf("%s ",str);
(*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars( env , str , str_JVM);
scanf("%s",buf);
return (*env)->NewStringUTF( env , buf);
}
```

The screen after the program ends looks like :

```
D:\UnderTest\JNI\StringPassing\Debug>java Prompt
09▀30≈ß#@÷gV
User Typed : V
```

Why don't i get the string `Type a String :` on cmd  when i run the program?

**Also:** my compiler underlines `(*env)` and points out that *Expression must have pointer type*. But when I compile I don't get any errors. Why is that and what is it?

Comment: which compiler are you using?

Comment: @ jogabonito `Microsoft visual c++ 2010 express` . Why ?

Comment: was wondering whether it was any difference between the C and C++ API. In C env is used as you did like `(*env) -> GetStringUTFChars( env , str , NULL);` .   In C++ it will be `env->GetStringUTFChars(str,NULL)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You pass `str` to `printf` when I'm pretty sure that you wanted to pass `str_JVM` to it instead.

```
str_JVM = (*env) -> GetStringUTFChars( env , str , NULL);
if( str_JVM == NULL ) return NULL;
printf("%s ",str_JVM);
```

Comment: can you also explain the second part of question ?

Comment: No, sorry. My C knowledge is very limited, someone else has to look at that part.

Answer (score 0):

As to the 2nd part of your question, JNIEnv is declared as a parameter to `Java_Prompt_myGetLine` as this type:

```
JNIEnv *env
```

That translates in English as "Declare a variable called env that is a pointer to an object of type JNIEnv".  The operator `->` in C and C++ is used for accessing members of a struct or class instance from a pointer, however, the left hand side of the `->` operator is expected to be a pointer.  This operator "[dereferences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dereference_operator)" the pointer.  Referencing a pointer like this: `*env` means "give me the object pointed to by env".  This also [dereferences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dereference_operator) the pointer.

The problem that your IDE is telling you is that lines such as this (there are 3 occurrences in your code above) are technically illegal code, because the `->` operator expects a pointer on the left-hand-side, but you have already dereferenced the pointer using `(*env)`, so your code is passing it an object instead of a pointer:

```
return (*env)->NewStringUTF( env , buf);
```

Your compiler is actually very forgiving by letting this compile anyway.  To correct it, change the line to either:

```
return env->NewStringUTF( env , buf);
```

-OR-

```
return (*env).NewStringUTF( env , buf);
```

Usually the first line is the more common usage (it looks cleaner).